How Can I Disable Lightningchart Scrolling Heatmap Automatic Color Transition
I am using a scrolling heatmap with several scrolling grid series to visualize data. However, there is a gap between the series where no data exists. I do not want anything to be drawn in these gaps, but the scrolling heatmap automatically fills them with colors. When new data arrives, these automatic colors are corrected based on the data, but if I stop feeding data to a specific series, the automatically drawn colors remain visible on the heatmap.
How can I disable this automatic drawing? (I believe these automatic drawings are intended to provide a smoother heatmap view, but I don’t want a smooth heatmap). Is there a configuration to turn this off?
I am using @lightningchart/lcjs version ^6.0.0. I have forked example from GitHub and created a new branch to recreate the issue. My code is accessable here: https://github.com/gurcankavakci/lcjs-example-0803-scrollingHeatmap/tree/issue-1-demo
I have also attached a screenshot illustrating the issue. In the screenshot, The series for 5 seconds with a 1-second space between them can be seen. The blue rectangles represent the actual data, while the green ones are not. These spaces should appear black.
How can I ensure these gaps are black (i.e., no drawing, just the background color)?

